# App Store Leave a Review/Rate iOS 8 Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a cell in the settings table view where i want to send the users straight to the Appstore and open the app page so they can leave a review. There is plenty of content about that in Stackoverflow but none worked for me in iOS8 with Swift.

Thanks.

Comment: So `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID"]];` does not work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if let checkURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.itunes.com/yourAppLlink.html") {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(checkURL) {
         println("url sucefully opened")
    }
} else {
    println("invalid url")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
var path: NSURL = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/YOUR_App_id")!

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(path)
```