# How to open Reviews Tab of App Store link of my app,so that user can give rating to my app in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried so many codes but it's not opening the Review tab of App Store.Can any one please provide the link for swift-3.Thanks in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715172/app-store-leave-a-review-rate-ios-8-swift?rq=1. It should be the same, I implemented it very similar last week

Answer (score 6):

Using this URL was the perfect solution for me. It takes the user directly to the `Write a Review section`. Credits to @Joseph Duffy. **MUST TRY**

URL = `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/idYOUR_APP_ID_HERE?action=write-review&mt=8`
Replace **YOUR_APP_ID_HERE** with your **AppId**

For a sample code try this :

Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1 :

```
 let openAppStoreForRating = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id1136613532?action=write-review&mt=8"
 if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: openAppStoreForRating)!) {
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: openAppStoreForRating)!)
 } else {
      showAlert(title: "Cannot open AppStore",message: "Please select our app from the AppStore and write a review for us. Thanks!!")
 }
```

Here showAlert is a custom function for an `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Kindly upvote if you like and select it as the Answer for your question.
Thanks

Comment: Can I ask some more question to you?

Comment: Does Apple provides iCloud API to access healthkit data which is synced to iCloud?

Comment: I suggest you to create a new question for this. It is not related here hence not following the community standards. Thanks